# JQuery dialog throws script error on 2nd load

Tags: jquery, dialog

**EDIT**
The page makes the ajax call the first time.  Then it modifies the DOM  of the page, right.  So the next time the user clicks on the link the page doesn't make the ajax call.  It just calls the open method on the dialog.  That is why the that line is not part of the ajax call.   I would have thought that the second time the user clicks the link the dialog displays quicker but it doesn't.  Its **much** slower.  Can anyone explain?

My page contains a link which opens a jquery dialog.  The code behind the link is

```
popup = $("#div").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 600,
    width: 1000,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    position: { my: "top center" },
    closeText: "Cancel",
    buttons: {
        "Add": function () {
            $("#frm").submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});



//get data for dialog
$.ajax({
    url: "/ControllerMethod/Controller",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "personID=" + personId + "&evidencetype=" + eType,
    success: function (data, event, xhr) {
        $("#div").html(data);               
    }
});        
popup.dialog("open");
```

note:popup, personId, eType have been previously defined.

The controller method the ajax calls into  is this

```
public ActionResult ControllerMethod(string category)
{
    Model1 model = new Model1();
    Model2 cat = new Model2(category);
    model.property.Add(cat);

    return PartialView("view", model);
}
```

This model contains about 1200 rows.  The dialog displays as expected the first time, but the second time it generates a script error about scripts taking too long to run.

What can I do to 1) get rid of the script error and 2) have the dialog display in a reasonable amt of time?

Thanks

Comment: the first thing i notice is popup.dialog("open"); is outside ajax. Since the dialog displays output of ajax, put it inside ajax success

Comment: since it takes time for ajax call to return, you can add beforeSend() to ajax to show "loading..." message